# Recaptcha form rendering in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha in my site using node.js, express, jade

code in express_test.js to render recaptcha html is

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var recaptcha = new Recaptcha(PUBLIC_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY);

    res.render('form', {
    layout: false,
    locals: {
        recaptcha_form: recaptcha.toHTML()
      }
   });
});
```

form.jade is

```
form(method='POST', action='/')
   != recaptcha_form
        input(type='submit', value='Check Recaptcha')
```

recaptcha.toHTML function is

```
Recaptcha.prototype.toHTML = function() {
var query_string = 'k=' + this.public_key;
if (this.error_code) {
    query_string += '&error=' + this.error_code;
}

var script_src = (this.is_secure ? "https://" : "http://") + SCRIPT_SRC + '?' + query_string;
var noscript_src = (this.is_secure ? "https://" : "http://") + NOSCRIPT_SRC + '?' + query_string;

return '<script type="text/javascript" src="' + script_src + '"></script>' +
       '<noscript><iframe src="' + noscript_src + '" height="300" width="500" ' +
       'frameborder="0"></iframe><br><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" ' +
       'rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input type="hidden" ' +
       'name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"></noscript>';
 };
```

when i run my server it does not render Recaptcha.prototype.toHTML function  why??